# sqlmap - Testing parameters when reading request from file

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

After hours of trial an error I decided to ask here for some advice.
I am currently trying to perform a sqlinj using using `sqlmap` on a system that was specifically designed to be attacked. 
The API states:

```
Method: GET
/users/>user_id</payments/>payment_token<

>user_id<: [int]
>payment_token<: [string]
```

Basically using the following command I can obtain information about a users payments:

```
curl -X GET 'https://123.123.123.123/users/2/payments/38d9f72f-cd26-fghf-a01f-804a9874eb0c' -H 'Authorization: Bearer abcdefghijklmop' -i -k
```

The token at the end is required for a valid request to perform any of the api requests. So what I did was logging the request by adding the `-v` at the end of my curl command.
This gave me the following request header:

```
GET /users/2/payments/38d9f72f-cd26-fghf-a01f-804a9874eb0c HTTP/1.1
Host: 123.123.123.123 
User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer abcdefghijklmop
```

I want to now check all parameters for vulnerabilities, so I tried to put the request in a txt file and than ran `sqlmap` like so:

```
sqlmap -r "/home/user/Documents/Pentesting/Results/header.txt" --risk=3 --level=3 --force-ssl -v 1
```

However this doesn't find anything. What else can I try? How do I explicitly state that sqlmap should try to inject every parameter?

header.txt looks like so:

```
GET /users/user_id=*/payments/payment_token=* HTTP/1.1
Host: 123.123.123.123
User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer abcdefghijklmop
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

> By default sqlmap tests all GET parameters and POST parameters.

*Source*: https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage (Injection -> Testable Parameters)

It would seem the issue isn't specifying that sqlmap needs to test all parameters.

I would suggest checking what the request headers look like, when you run your last command.

EDIT: I typically don't see variables replaced with asterisk in the file.